# getting error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, ado

I am trying to code "insert,delete,update,display" options to sql with Ado.Net for my assignment. As I am still learning, my code maybe lengthy. Please check and say me where I am making the error. The code is half way through (only coded for insert).

Error I get is:

[image]

my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Crud
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--What do you want to do?--");            
            Console.WriteLine(" 1. Insert\n 2. Update\n 3. Delete\n 4. Display\n");
            int choice=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Student name:");
                string SName=Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter Student Mobile Number:");
                string SMob = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter student fees:");
                string Sfees = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter student course:");                
                string course=Console.ReadLine();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Sachin-PC;Initial Catalog=ADOProject;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into focusstudents values(@name,@mobile,@fees,@course)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",SName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile",SMob);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fees", Sfees);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                int l = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (l > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inserted Successfully");
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from focusstudents";
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0}{1}", dr[0], dr[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is no data to display, add any data to be shown here");
                    }
                }
                con.Close();            
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `AddWithValue()`, explicitly add with the appropriate type.

Comment: Do you have any extra columns in focusstudents table? Mismatch in column list.  Change "insert into focusstudents (column1, column2..) values (...)"

Comment: i have a primary key column as "id"

Comment: @sachin Is that auto number enabled like seeding? If not you have to enable it or pass max id + 1

Comment: yes that was the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the additional information in your exception? That one is useful error message.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Simple, change your insert query like below:

```
insert into focusstudents (column1, column2, column3, column4) values(@name,@mobile,@fees,@course)
```

It will work. This will make sure the passing values are mapped promptly. Even if you add any columns later in table definition, this will not break.

**Update**: The primary key column should be configured to get auto seeding or have to handle in code to get unique Id on insert.